# How to check if parent element include children with spesific class with useEffect and UseRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to **accordion-content** class if include **link-active** or not. So I created the code like that.

```js
import {React, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const accordionOperation = useRef(null);
  const [isOperationActive, setOperationActive] = useState(false);
  const [isOperationOpen, setOperationOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const accordionOperationChildren = accordionOperation.current?.children;
    for (let i = 0; i < accordionOperationChildren?.length; i++) {
      if (accordionOperationChildren[i].classList.contains("link-active")) {
        setOperationActive(true);
      } else {
        setOperationActive(false);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ul className="accordion-content" ref={accordionOperation}>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/bee"
          className={({ isActive }) => (
            isActive ? "link-active" : "disable"
          )}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Bees</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/command"
          className={({ isActive }) => (
            isActive ? "link-active" : "disable"
          )}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Commands</li>
        </NavLink>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But my state called `isOperationActive` doesn't change according to **active-link**
I am using `Navlink` components from `react-dom`. So when I click on any link the link become active.

[image]

So how can I keep my `isOperationActive` state updated?

**This is rest of my code**

```js
<div className="accordion operations">
  <div className="accordion-item">
    <div
      className="accordion-title"
      role="button"
      tabIndex={0}
      onClick={() => setOperationOpen(!isOperationOpen)}
    >
      <div
        className={isOperationOpen
        ? "accordion-title-head "
        : "accordion-title-head"}
      >
        <ArrowsHorizontal style={{ paddding: "4px" }} />
        <div className={"dropdownOperation"}>Operations</div>
        <div className="text-white">
          {isOperationOpen ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {isOperationOpen && (
      <ul className="accordion-content" ref={accordionOperation}>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/bee"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Bees</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/command"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Commands</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/company"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Companies</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/dashboard"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Dashboards</li>
        </NavLink>{" "}
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/device-profile"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Device Profiles</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/location"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Location</li>
        </NavLink>{" "}
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/route"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Routes</li>
        </NavLink>{" "}
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/sub"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Subscriptions</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/trackable"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Trackables</li>
        </NavLink>{" "}
        <NavLink
          to="/hc20/user"
          className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "disable")}
        >
          <li className="aside_list-item">Users</li>
        </NavLink>
      </ul>
    )}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you're assuming that once your if-statement within your `for` loop evaluates to `true` and performs `setOperationActive(true);` your for loop will stop checking for other elements. But this doesn't happen. The subsequent iterations of your for loop that look at your other elements will call `setOperationActive(false);` in the `else`-block, as a result not setting your state to `true` as you expect.

Generally, if you find yourself trying to set state in a loop (that doesn't break when you do so), you're most likely doing something wrong. The idea is that you should only need to set your state value once. What you set that state value to though can be computed with a loop, but the setting of that value should only need to occur once, eg:

```js
const accordionOperationChildren = accordionOperation.current?.children;
let active = false; // determines what we set out state value to
for (let i = 0; i < accordionOperationChildren?.length && !active; i++) { // stop looping if active is true or we've reached the end of our children
  if (accordionOperationChildren[i].classList.contains("link-active")) {
    active = true;
  } 
}
setOperationActive(active); // only call this once
```

There are other ways we can write the above, such as using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const accordionOperationChildren = Array.from(accordionOperation.current?.children ?? []);
const active = accordionOperationChildren.some(
  elem => elem.classList.contains("link-active")
);
setOperationActive(active);
```

Or you can use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to check if you have a match:

```js
const activeLink = Boolean(accordionOperation.current?.querySelector(".active-link"));
setOperationActive(activeLink);
```

the above is slightly different from what you're doing, as this doesn't just search the immediate children of `accordion-content`, but it also searches the nested children (ie: each `<a>` tag's children) for an element that matches the `active-link` class. If this is an issue (which juding by your HTML screenshot doesn't look like it will be), you could also use [`:scope` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#browser_compatibility) (bearing in mind its browser availability) with the child combinator selector:

```js
const activeLink = Boolean(accordionOperation.current?.querySelector(":scope > .active-link"));
setOperationActive(activeLink);
```

Comment: am i have to call them inside useEffect(). Because still couldnt make it working. My accordion-content class only appear when my another hook is true. So my accordion-content class depends on  if "isOperationOpen" hook. I am attaching the my other code. I also added to useEffect a dependency "isOperationOpen" but didnt work.

Comment: using some() throws this error "Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)
"

Comment: That's a typescript error. You need to type `accordionOperationChildren` correctly (you haven't tagged typescript or mentioned typescript in your question). Please create a [mre] so that it's easier to debug and see the issue.